# How to run selenium script on Safari Browser in Mac Machine

Tags: java, safari, selenium-webdriver

I am having a selenium code which is running successfully on Windows 7 for Safari Browser but when i running similar code in MAc Machine in Safari Browser.

But i am getting error. It is opening new Safari Browser but not hitting the URL.
My piece of code is:=

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I have also gone through the official website but that is also not working.

Error i am getting is:-Exception in thread "main" `org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 45092 ms`

Answer (score 1):

Its a known bug.

Here is the bug [detail](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=7091)

Comment: thats helpful. Even I'm facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

On MAC-System, in Safari browser -safari webdriver will be installed by default.To make selenium scripts to run on safari browser you have to make following settings in browser:

Provide the default setting for the Selenium Webdriver Extension:

1. Click on “Safari” > “Preferences” > “Extensions” > You will find Selenium extension
2. Select “Enable Webdriver”

Safari Webdriver setup():

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Now all the settings are done and now we should be able to launch our Selenium scripts using Safari browser

Answer (score 0):

The old SafariDriver implementation is no longer maintained and should not be used. You do not need to download anything besides Safari 10 to get the Apple-developed driver. This article explains everything https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/